# Can I use Vivaldi as the browser for live preview in Bracket?

Tags: configuration, adobe-brackets, live-preview, vivaldi

I am a new comer of Bracket and coding. I normally do not use Chrome as my default browser. However it seems like the live preview in Bracket can only be functioned with Chrome. I really do not want to download an extra browser in this reason. Can I use Vivaldi, my default browser as the browser for live preview in Bracket? What should I do if yes?

Comment: Yes, is posible use with other browsers. I use the live preview with Firefox. You have to activate _Experimental Live Preview_ (maybe is different the text because I haven`t in English) in _File_ menu.

Comment: Yea i have tried this, meanwhile i have make the "livedev.multibrowser" becomes true in value. The consequence is when i click on the "Live Preview" button, there will be no response, the button icon will be filled with color half and keep connecting

Comment: I try with Vivaldi and no problem: https://s31.postimg.org/fhx7fo3i3/vivaldi.png  What is your SO? I have problems with live preview in Linux but works fine in Windows

Comment: Windows 8.1. Here's the snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/5qgA3JQ.png

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you, works fine for me. Is experimental feature so could be buggy

Comment: Alrite never mind, thanks for your help